# Spring data rest - Handle entity validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

This is the Code

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
class Person {
   @Id private Long Id;
   @NotNull private String name;
   //getter setters
}
```

**PersonRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path="person" )
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person,Long>{
}
```

Now,  when I send null against name attribute  , the validator validates it correctly, but the actual exception that is getting thrown is TransactionRollbackExecption.

Like this

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-03-14T09:01:08.533+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction",
    "path": "/peron"
}
```

How do I get the actual ConstraintViolation exception. I do see the exception in logs. But its not getting thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [LocalValidatorFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html) to [ValidatingRepositoryEventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/event/ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.html) when configuring [RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_assigning_validators_manually), like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RepoRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    private final LocalValidatorFactoryBean beanValidator;

    public RepoRestConfig(LocalValidatorFactoryBean beanValidator) {
        this.beanValidator = beanValidator;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
        v.addValidator("beforeCreate", beanValidator);
        v.addValidator("beforeSave", beanValidator);
        super.configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: using the handler is a slightly more convenient way, as it lets you work with the object in a type-safe way (e.g. Person, not Object - which is the case when using Validator).

Comment: @hovanessyan the question was about 'how to get ConstraintViolation' not about 'how to validate my entity'...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Spring's `TransactionInterceptor` is overriding your exception.

The idiomatic way of implementing repository entity validation, according to [Spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation), is to use Spring Data Rest Events. You probably want to use [`BeforeSaveEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/event/BeforeSaveEvent.html) or [`BeforeCreateEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/event/BeforeCreateEvent.html).

You can create a custom type-safe handler for entities (see the provided link for details), which looks similar to:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class PersonEventHandler {

  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handlePersonSave(Person p) {
    // … you can now deal with Person in a type-safe way
  }
}
```

Another approach is to register a Repository Listener which extends [`AbstractRepositoryEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/event/AbstractRepositoryEventListener.html), also described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. but I was looking for something generic. Above answer solves it